# python module not working for non-root (installed as egg)

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04

I have a *semi-legacy* system, where I cannot install `pip` and I am managing
packages via `.egg` which I build from the sources.
I wanted to upgrade `paramiko`, and for that I was manually installing all 
the dependent packages, all installed well except `cryptography`

The module installed and works for `root` (or `sudo`) but not for the 
unprivileged user.
I have set the `PYTHONPATH` for the unprivileged user and its same as
that of the `root`s `sys.path`, still I see get `ImportError`!
The egg file in installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`
and I have `chown`ed all egg files to `777` !

I am not sure what else is missing here! Also, I don't understand
why only `cryptography` is not accessible to the unprivileged user
whereas all other egg files/modules are accessible.

Can anyone give me some hints/guide me here please ...

I have `Python-2.7` on `Ubuntu 14.04.2`

Answer (score 0):

Had the subdir of `cryptography` in `PYTHONPATH`, it should have ended at `..egg`!
And had to change ownership of all the `.egg` files and directories to that of
the unprivileged user (`chown -R myuser:myuser ...`)